# how to implement CCL::DOUBLE-FLOAT-FROM-BITS function

Tags: common-lisp

I want to use the cl-olefs package.But I found it cantains a plantform dependent function double-float-from-bits.

So I want to write the function double-float-from-bits can run on any plantform independently.
But I have no idea how to implment it.

Or are there some independent functions like double-float-from-bits which can be replaced into
cl-olefs package.

Comment: You probably want to look here: http://www.cliki.net/ieee-floats . At my time I also first rushed to implement it, but then found this package.

Answer (score 4):

Something along these lines. This is not terribly efficient, but should be quite portable.

```
(defun double-float-from-bits (high low)
  (let* ((negative (not (zerop (logand high #x80000000))))
         (mant (+ low (* #x100000000 (logand high #xfffff))))
         (exbits (logand (ash high -20) #x7ff))
         (ex (coerce (expt 2 (- exbits 1075)) 'double-float))
         (base (coerce (+ #x10000000000000 mant) 'double-float)))
    (cond ((and (zerop exbits)
                (zerop mant))
           (if negative -0.0 0.0))
          ((zerop exbits)
           'subnormal)
          ((and (= #x7ff exbits)
                (zerop mant))
           (if negative 'negative-infinity 'positive-infinity))
          ((= #x7ff exbits)
           'not-a-number)
          (negative
           (- (* base ex)))
          (t
           (* base ex)))))
```

Note that Common Lisp spec does not require the internal floating point representation to be that of IEEE 754; the requirements are a bit less strict. Additionally, there are no means of portably expressing infinities or not-a-numbers, and I chose to simply not support subnormals.

Also, there may be small rounding errors, depending on your implementation.